# Sympy solveset can't find answer

Tags: python, sympy, trigonometry, symbolic-math

I have a very simple equation `sin(t) - t = 0`, but Sympy can't figure it out. When I do:

```
solveset(sin(t) - t, t)
```

All I get is:

[image]

Although the answer is obviously 0. Anyone has a clue?

Comment: By default solveset solves over the complex numbers in which case this equation has infinitely many solutions that can not be expressed using ordinary mathematical functions. With `solveset(..., Reals)` it should be possible to find the unique solution at `0` but I guess that case is not yet handled by `solveset`.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin setting ```Reals``` or even ```Interval(0, 1)``` gives the same answer, that's why I didn't include those, but I forgot in C this has infinite solutions...